# How to change my default TeX editor under Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, texworks, texshop

I'm using Mac OS X and the default tex editor is TexWorks, but I want to utilize TexShop as the default one.

Comment: I think this is off-topic ...

Comment: This depends on your operating system not LaTeX.

Comment: Do "Get Info" from a `.tex` file; then change the default application for all file of the same kind. Of course, assuming that you're using Mac OS X. Otherwise there's no TeXShop to begin with.

Comment: @egreg: please make comment an answer.  I think this question is very much on topic.  So what if the intervention needs to be made at the operating system level instead of the application level?

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you're on Mac OS X (otherwise there would be no TeXShop available to you), all you need is to click on a `.tex` file in a Finder window and choose "Get Info" from the "File" menu.

In the window that pops up go at the tab named "Open with" and from the popup menu choose "TeXShop.app"

Then click on the button just below, named "Change All…"

[image: screen shot]

**Warning**:
please note that this changes the behavior of **ALL** [!] files with the suffix `.tex`.

If, for some reason, you later want to open single .tex files with another application like a pure text editor, you can change the setting for those files by hand in the "Get Info" panel, or you can Control-click on an individual file in the Finder and choose the application to open that file on a one-time basis.