# How to get source code on texshop?

Tags: editors, texshop, macos

I am using Texshop. I created a file there and saved it then there are 5 files saved but no of them is about my source code. Please tell me how can I access my source code so that I could edit it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Open the `.tex` file (extension `.tex`). For further help please post a `ls` on your directory.

Comment: Are you asking where the files are saved?

Comment: Try TeXShop's File->Recent Files menu item. Then Cmd-Click on the Window title and a full path to the document will be shown.

Comment: This might be a dublicate question of another ine

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

A simple `my-file.tex` file in TeXShop will generate the following five files:

```
my-file.tex
my-file.aux
my-file.log
my-file.pdf
my-file.synctex.gz
```

The source file is `my-file.tex`.  You can probably access it through the File  -> Open Recent menu from within TeXShop (assuming your Mac preferences are set up that way).

Depending on how your Finder is set up, the extensions may or may not be shown.  I find it helpful to always show file extensions in the Finder. You can do this by going to the Finder Preferences -> Advanced and clicking on Show All Filename Extensions.

If the file opens with the wrong application, select the file in the Finder and choose Get Info. From there you can choose the application to open the file with. Choose TeXShop and click the box that says Open All with this application.

See  [How to change my default TeX editor under Mac OS X?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42910/2693)

[image]

Comment: When I am opening .tex file, It is being opened in LatexiT but not in Texshop. I want to open it in Texshop

Comment: @prashantsharma See edit.

Comment: @prashantsharma If this answer solved your problem, it's helpful to "Accept" it by clicking on the green check mark below the voting buttons at the left of the answer.